# Por que recebi a medalha "capelo" no meta?

Tags: suporte, status-intencional, meta, medalhas

Recebi a medalha "capelo" (mortarboard - não seria melhor "beca"?) no meta, por ter ganho 200 rep no dia. Mas o meta não tem rep. Por que essa medalha aparece no meu perfil do meta, e não no principal?

Comment: Não sabia que o bônus de associação contava para o limite de reputação do dia. Será que isso vale para todos os sites? Acho que não deveria, mesmo que isso afete apenas uma vez.

Comment: Eu acho que o bônus não conta para o "cap", mas pelo visto conta para a medalha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O ganho de reputação nos Metas existe, só não é visível. Então é possível ganhar seu capelo.

Um dia a gente vai ter uma lista tão grande [quanto a do Arqade.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard)

Comment: Interessante, eu não sabia disso! Daí deduzo que o bônus de associação não vale para esta medalha no site principal, certo? Porque no mesmo dia passei de 200 lá, mas devido ao bônus.

Comment: Não que eu me preocupe tanto, mas vai ficar "capelo" que me parece ser adequado para portugueses? Ou vai mudar para beca que é o que brasileiros estão acostumados? Ou achar outro nome mais criativo ainda?

Comment: @bfavaretto O bônus de associação não conta.

Comment: @bigown Isso é uma ótima (ainda que "irrelevante") pergunta... Capelo é o nome do chapéu de formatura mesmo no Brasil, mas ninguém sabe disso (eu não sabia, até ver a lista de traduções das medalhas). Talvez beca seja mais apropriado por conta da familiaridade de todos, mesmo que não corresponda diretamente ao sentido original. Não sei.

Comment: Curiosamente essa semana passou o programa "O Mundo Segundo os Brasileiros" em Portugal e mostrando a Universidade de Coimbra, foi falado que todos alunos de direito usavam capelo nas aulas. Todos foram mostrados vestindo o que conhecemos como beca (ou capa do Joaquim Barbosa :) ) e nenhum chapéu. O Google diz que é chapéu mesmo.