# Como dar destaque a uma pergunta do meta?

Tags: suporte, meta, gratificação, boletim-da-comunidade

No metão, é muito comum os usuários adicionarem gratificações (*bounties*) a determinadas perguntas para chamar a atenção da comunidade ou da equipe da SE sobre determinado assunto.

Com uma gratificação, aumenta a chance de a pergunta aparecer na home do site, próxima ao topo da lista (especialmente no final do período de 7 dias), além de ser listada separadamente em outra aba.

No nosso meta não existe reputação (aliás, existe, mas [escondida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/65/por-que-recebi-a-medalha-capelo-no-meta#477)), portanto não é possível colocar gratificações. Como fazer se quisermos dar destaque para um assunto? Editar a pergunta para lançá-la ao topo da lista ajuda, mas será que é suficiente (principalmente no futuro, quando, esperamos, o meta será ainda mais movimentado)? Como isso funciona nos demais metas por site? Seria possível ao menos forçar que determinada pergunta apareça no Boletim da Comunidade? (Boletim da Comunidade é o nome oficial daquela caixa amarela à direita, que diz "em destaque no meta" e "debates mais ativos".)

Comment: Fiz __[um post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216025/ideas-for-calling-attention-to-questions-in-meta-of-se-sites-without-bounty)__ no Meta.EN

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### [Resposta do Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216027/167534) à [pergunta do Sergio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216025/167534) no metão

Gratificações não são uma boa maneira de chamar a atenção nem no MSO (o único meta onde elas existem). Às vezes elas são boas para enquetes, mas existem maneiras melhores de conseguir atenção:

- Escrever um título claro e cativante pode estimular as pessoas a seguir o link
- Garantir que as postagens sejam devidamente classificadas com tags pode ajudar as pessoas certas a encontrá-las (não classifique debates como [novo-recurso](/questions/tagged/novo-recurso), não classifique pedidos de suporte como [debate](/questions/tagged/debate)), e tente incluir ao menos uma tag que define que parte do site, software ou processo você quer discutir.
- Postar respostas com informações úteis pode encoragar os outros a responderem também
- Votar a favor em [debate](/questions/tagged/debate)s pode [levá-los ao boletim da comunidade](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-is-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined)
- Investir tempo para descrever os passos exatos para reproduzir um bug, ou comparar prós e contras em solicitações de [novo-recurso](/questions/tagged/novo-recurso) pode ajudar os desenvolvedores a resolver o problema mais rapidamente.

Comment: O Shog9 diz que parece haver um bug com [o algoritmo que puxa debates para o boletim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/167534), pois um dos 4 slots deveria estar sendo ocupado pela discussão, enquanto os outros 3 estão travados por posts com a tag [meta-tag:destaque]. **Gabe: daria para tirar o destaque de um desses 3?**

Comment: Pensei em talvez adicionar a meta tag boletim-da-comunidade à pergunta (?). Deixo registrado que, seguindo o fio da pergunta do Sergio, achei [aqui como funcionam as regras do que aparece no boletim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-are-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined/130893#130893)

Comment: @brasofilo Com que intenção? Sugerir que seja colocada a tag [meta-tag:destaque]? Porque isso força a pergunta para a seção superior do boletim (a inferior é automática)

Comment: Não, não se trata de colocar [destaque] aqui. Pensei que esta pergunta podia ser interessante quando listar a tag [boletim], mas é só um palpite. . . . Deixei o link acima porque explica o peso de cada coisa no boletim, já que esta é única pergunta que achei que fala de "destaque+boletim". . . . Sim, sim, o boletim com dois destaques deixa espaço só pra dois Debates Ativos, *not so good, no?*

Comment: Agora eu entendi, @brasofilo. Fiz uma pequena edição e incluí a tag. Esses *slots* do boletim acho que o Shog pode alterar (talvez o Gabe também), se houver pressão suficiente... PS: já já limpo essa nossa conversa.