# Como funciona a reputação entre o site principal e o meta?

Tags: suporte, meta, reputação

Estou bem confuso aqui. Vejam meu cenário:

- Me cadastrei no pt.stackoverflow.com
- Ganhei +100 reputação por ter reputação suficiente em outro site da rede (101 rep)
- Respondi uma pergunta e ganhei alguns votos positivos, +20 (121 rep)
- Entrei no meta.pt.stackoverflow.com e minha reputação aqui é 121.

No Stack Overflow internacional, a reputação do site principal e do meta são independentes. Mas visto o cenário acima, pensei que aqui esta reputação fosse compartilhada. Mas agora recebi alguns votos positivos em ambos os sites e estes não se refletem na reputação do outro.

Como funciona a reputação entre o site principal e o meta aqui?

**Edit:** (usando o meu poder de dedução) É mostrada apenas a maior reputação entre os dois sites em ambos (com um pequeno intervalo de atualização)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fabrício, é exatamente como você deduziu.

O [**Meta principal**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) tem reputação própria. Os outros metas "locais" têm a mesma reputação que o sub-site em questão. Neste caso o SOpt tem o seu próprio *meta*. Pode ler um post sobre isso [**aqui**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/). <sup>Em Inglês</sup>.

Porém o [**Gabe referiu**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/447/129) que a reputação aqui no meta é registada, mas não mostrada. A parte das medalhas funciona à parte, independente do site principal e do mesmo modo que o Meta principal.

Assim, e como você referiu: A reputação aqui no meta é a mesma que o site principal, com um breve atraso de atualização por parte do software/servidores.

Comment: A reputação que conta é a do site principal então. Muito obrigado pelo detalhamento extra sobre medalhas e o link para o post do blog que eu não tinha visto ainda, esclareceu todas dúvidas que eu poderia vir a ter.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, bom ter você aqui na comunidade SOpt!

Comment: @CypherPotato o que você corrigiu é diferença entre pt_PT e pt_BR não é um erro de escrita.

Comment: @CypherPotato [Devemos “corrigir” português de Portugal? Exemplo, o termo “por defeito”](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462/70)

Comment: @Bacco após pesquisar, vi que existe a palavra _registada_ na grafia portuguesa (e não brasileira). Foi por ora que senti a necessidade de corrigir. Então, assumi o PT_BR porque é a linguagem mais utilizada aqui no site, mas se tiver outra posição sobre essa edição, podemos começar uma discussão aqui no meta sobre.

Comment: @CypherPotato apontei o link justamente pq já houve a discussão (apesar de ter ficado nos comments daquela, meio que há um consenso no meta sobre isso) - Talvez seja o caso de postar um wiki lá depois só pra formalizar

Comment: @Bacco decidi reverter a edição. Após um breve debate no chat, vi que não era necessária a edição. O ideal é utilizar palavras que coexistam no PTBR e no PTPT, no entanto, _Registrar_ não existe em Portugal, assim como _Registar_ não existe no Brasil.