# Qual seria minha reputação no Meta?

Tags: suporte, data-explorer

Oficialmente, o Meta não tem reputação, mas essa informação consta no banco de dados como se pode ver em **[Como funciona a reputação entre o site principal e o meta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/723/201)**

Como podemos calcular então essa reputação "virtual"?

Comment: A gente tá no escuro quanto ao feedback de nossa meta-participação. Por favor, apoiem esta feature-request: [**Make voting activity on your posts available on site metas (what you would get from rep if metas had rep)**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167648/185667)

Comment: Apareceu uma resposta no link acima que tem uma ferramenta bacana que mostra score e atividade da nossa participação: [Meta Activity Monitor](http://jsbin.com/ximuhuzo/1?poll=no&interval=77&sitename=meta.pt.stackoverflow&userid=201)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pergunta [*How to calculate per site meta reputation?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172242/185667) tem uma resposta com algumas queries úteis:

- [Histórico da reputação do Gabe](http://data.stackexchange.com/ptme/query/203302/user-reputation-history?uid=12#graph)
- [Top 20 usuários nas últimas 200 semanas](http://data.stackexchange.com/ptme/query/196452/top-users-rep-per-x-weeks?numofweeks=200&top=20#resultSets)

Achei uma query para adaptar e esta vai direto ao ponto:

> http://data.stackexchange.com/ptme/query/225376/reputacao-virtual-no-meta-para-o-usuario-x

Comment: Interessante, minha reputação no meta é/seria mais ou menos a mesma da no site principal.

Comment: Droga! Agora temos mais um ranking para disputar... E vc tá na minha cola, vou ter que responder mais </joke>

Comment: @Math, esse ranking específico do Meta já existe aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation e aí também tou na sua cola =P

Comment: @brasofilo hahaha.. não estou gostando dessa perseguição, preciso tomar providencias. Mas.. esse link que você passou agora mostra um ranking bem diferente, aparentemente ele rankeia por participação, seja lá qual é a formula para calcular a participação de um usuário vejo que não é apenas a reputação no Meta, não é mesmo?

Comment: O link http://data.stackexchange.com/ptme/query/220691/minha-meta-reputacao não tá mostrando a reputação do Meta, mas sim a do site principal. Tem algum erro na sua query.

Comment: @Math, pô, jurava que tava funcionando... não sei como consertar :/

Comment: A tab de *meta-participation* é o conjunto da participação (votos em posts e comments, posts, comentários, reviews). @Math