# Devemos "corrigir" português de Portugal? Exemplo, o termo "por defeito"

Tags: debate

O termo é "**por defeito**"

Não é a primeira vez que encontro esse termo e numa rápida pesquisa entendi que parece ser português de Portugal https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/defeito

O post específico onde encontrei: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9521/4793

> ...e se tiver PHP com versão inferior a 5.4 os caracteres **por defeito** são
>   ISO-8859-1, entre 5.4 e 5.6 sã...

Para o português do Brasil dá a entender que se trata de um **defeito**, uma **falha** e não um padrão pré definido conforme é o significado em Portugual.

Para quem é mais atento e está ciente de que existem muitos membros de Portugal, é tolerável e compreensível. Mas ainda assim causa confusão.

Uma sugestão é usar o termo em inglês "default" no lugar de "por defeito".

Há outros debates sobre o assunto, porém é mais focado em casos análogos. Aqui temos um caso ambíguo.

Comment: Eu podia jurar que já vi essa discussão específica do "por defeito", mas não encontrei link. Talvez tenha sido em comentários em alguma das postagens relacionadas. O assunto geral de pt_BR e pt_PT foi levantado em algumas ocasiões diferentes, tanto por iniciativa de usuários no Meta, quanto edição de posts por questões meramente regionais.

Comment: Em duas resposta diz para não mecher e manter o original. A do @Gabe deixa um "porém" -> `"Melhor esperar pra ver o que acontece. Por enquanto, escreva como quiser."`

Comment: Lembrava mesmo do assunto, em 2014 eu fiz uma consideração sobre o mesmo termo: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1670/utilizar-utilizadores-em-vez-de-usu%c3%a1rios#comment4789_1670

Comment: Quando percebo que é característica linguística, eu não mexo, e se vejo em edição, rejeito. Editar esse tipo de coisa eu entendo que seria quase que descaracterizar a forma de falar do cara, porque ele mora em outro país cujo idioma, apesar de ser o mesmo nosso, tem peculiaridades que nos soam diferentes. Acredito que também há peculiaridades na forma que falamos que nossos amigos lusitanos devem estranhar também, ambos podem conviver, desde que haja entendimento do contexto em si.

Comment: Situação análoga http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1670/utilizar-utilizadores-em-vez-de-usu%c3%a1rios

Comment: é que nesse caso específico dá uma interpretação errada. no Brasil, "padrão" e "por defeito" são muito distintos

Comment: Creio que é mera questão de deixar uma observação para o autor, nestes casos, sugerindo o termo default e explicando que tem um sentido menos ambíguo. Se for editar a pergunta para ajustar outras coisas essenciais, num caso muito extremo onde haja "risco de dano" poderia até aproveitar e por _default_ italizado, mas deixando uma observação na razão da edição, para que o autor não se ofenda. Eu trataria caso a caso (provavelmente não mexeria, acho que não dá pra "culpar" o autor pela falta de cultura do leitor). Eu sou mais na linha do "quem não entender que comente perguntando".

Comment: @DanielOmine acho que é melhor do que tentar por uma regra, pq mesmo se a gente combinar aqui, o autor original provavelmente não vai ler, e temos que ter esse cuidado de explicar de qualquer forma. Minha sugestão é usar o bom senso caso a caso mesmo. Se não afetar o essencial da resposta, melhor nem mexer. Se for algo que realmente atrapalhe, sugerir alteração, deixar comentário para os outros leitores, e nos casos mais extremos, editar e deixar um aviso educado. Mas somente em "casos extremos".

Comment: Editei.. Fiz um print para destacar onde mudei: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwFfy.png

Comment: Eu ainda entendo que a discussão caberia numa resposta lá na outra, mas se pensa em reabertura, eu sugeriria começar por um título específico sobre o assunto, e linkando as outras discussões sobre linguagem, deixando na introdução da pergunta que esse é um caso específico. Eu tb enxugaria o corpo da postagem só tratando deste ponto. Não sei se isso é suficiente para reabertura (ou se a reabertura traria algum benefício de fato, pois a duplicata permanece indefinidamente no site, e mesmo fechada serve para link), mas é uma possibilidade.

Comment: @Bacco já ouve sim essa discussão que eu lembro-me de participar.

Comment: [Vamos continuar essa discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48648/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-bruno-costa)

Comment: @Bacco http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23532/toda-div-tem-posi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-relativa/23534#comment43443_23534

Comment: tem um monte de casos:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=por+defeito

Comment: @DanielOmine porque é muito usado pelo menos no norte e acho que também no centro de Portugal, alias foi na Universidade que eu aprendi essa expressão.

Comment: Acho que esta resposta no PL diz tudo: [Origem do termo “por defeito”](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/619/153)

Comment: Ótimo link @JorgeB.

Comment: Eu antes usava "por defeito" por defeito, mas de facto "por defeito" tem defeito, não é a melhor tradução para *by default*. Por isso agora, sempre que me lembro, uso "por padrão" por defeito. Bolas! voltei a esquecer, agora uso, por padrão, "por padrão". :)